# How do I find the probability that of four picked balls no one is orange?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I have the following problems.

> In a box we have $3$ balls of color green, violet, orange, blue (so in total $12$ balls). We pick four of them without replacements, what is the probability that there is no orange ball among the four?

My idea was the following, let us define $$\Omega=\left\{f:\{1,2,3,4\}\rightarrow \{g,g,g,v,v,v,o,o,o,b,b,b\}~s.t.~f ~~\text{is injective}\right\}$$ then $|\Omega|=12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9$. Now define $\Lambda\subset \Omega$ such that for $(a,b,c,d)\in \Lambda$ we have $a,b,c,d\neq o$.So we only have $9$ elements which we can use, i.e. $|\Lambda|=9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6$. Therefore $$\Bbb{P}(\Lambda)=\frac{9\cdot 8\cdot 7\cdot 6}{12\cdot 11\cdot 10\cdot 9}=\frac{14}{55}$$

Does this work so or is this completely wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, probability can't be more than $1$ can it ?

Comment: ah no it can't but do you see the mistake?

Comment: So I corrected a mistake is it better now?

Comment: Your question itself is riddled with errors. You ask for P(no red) but there is no mention of red balls being in the mix !

Comment: sorry better now?

Comment: I don't know since this is our first exercise sheet. In the lecture he always wanted to do it with such a set $\Omega$ and $\lambda$ but also mentionned that sometimes it is really hard to find a nice way describing $\Omega$. But basically your way is equal to a part of mine so I don't think they will mark this as wrong

Comment: My answer assumed that you specified one of the colors as *orange*, when you intended *red*.  Otherwise, as already commented, your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

In your edited question, your answer is correct and your analysis is good.  However, in my opinion, a better approach to these *types* of questions is a *combinatorics* approach, where the probability is computed as

$$\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}}.$$

$D$ which represents the total number of ways of selecting $4$ distinct balls, without replacement, from the $(12)$ balls, where order of selection is (arbitrarily) deemed irrelevant is equal to

$$ \binom{12}{4}.$$

With the $(3)$ red balls excluded from selection, $N$ then  represents the total number of ways of selecting $4$ distinct balls, without replacement, from the $(9)$ remaining balls.  Again, order of selection is regarded as irrelevant, primarily because the numerator and denominator must be computed in a consistent manner.  So, $N$ equals

$$ \binom{9}{4}.$$

The (somewhat) alternative approach, that more closely relates to your mathematical calculations is to regard order of selection as important in **both** the numerator and denominator.  Then, you have that

$$N = \frac{9!}{(9-4)!} ~~\text{and}~~ D = \frac{(12)!}{[(12) - 4]!}.$$